# Google Plus SDK Call back for share

Tags: ios, google-plus

I have integrated Google Plus SDK for ios and setup everything for share. But is there a callback after the share display popup is opened AND THEN user shares or cancels the share. I want to know the delegate method where it says this.
I know that `-(void)finishedSharingWithError:(NSError *)error` is the delegate method but its not being called.
Here is my code for sharing via google plus..

```
  -(void)postToGooglePlus:(PostModel *)parameter{

GPPSignIn *signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
signIn.shouldFetchGooglePlusUser = YES;
signIn.clientID = kClientId;
signIn.scopes = @[ kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin ];
signIn.delegate = self;
[signIn authenticate];
}


- (void)finishedWithAuth: (GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth
               error: (NSError *) error {
NSLog(@"Received error %@ and auth object %@",error, auth);


id<GPPNativeShareBuilder> shareBuilder = [[GPPShare sharedInstance] nativeShareDialog];

[shareBuilder setPrefillText:@"This is a test"];
[shareBuilder open];

}

-(void)finishedSharingWithError:(NSError *)error{
    if(!error){
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to set `<GPPShareDelegate>` to your view controller first. After that set `delegate` like this in your `- (void)finishedWithAuth: (GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth error: (NSError *) error`method:

```
id<GPPNativeShareBuilder> shareBuilder = [[GPPShare sharedInstance] nativeShareDialog];
[GPPShare sharedInstance].delegate = self;
```

You will now be able to call `-(void)finishedSharingWithError:(NSError *)error` or `-(void)finishedSharing:(BOOL)shared` accordingly.

Comment: I have set `<GPPShareDelegate>` still its not happening

Comment: trying and commenting.